# cron generating a space in dynamic filename

Tags: date, centos, cron

I have this **`cron`** job:

```
*/1 * * * * mysqldump -uroot -pPassword --single_transaction --opt dbname | gzip > /home/incredible/backup/dbname_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d-\%k\%M\%S"`.sql.gz
```

The problem is, the resulting file has a **space** on it, which I am confuse where it came from.

**FILE GENERATED**

```
dbname_20130517- 54701.sql.gz
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
dbname_20130517-54701.sql.gz
```

Comment: The percent signs hardly need to be backslash-escaped.

Answer (score 0):

The format string is a bit off:

```
$ date +"%Y%m%d-%k%M%S"
20130517- 22256
```

The problem is the %k:  "hour, space padded ( 0..23); same as %_H".
Use %H instead if that's an option:

```
$ date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"
20130517-022253
```